# Enable UDF in Transfer screen (IN304000) on release Status

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

I am trying to enable an UDF in transfer screen on release status, but the UDF is not getting enabled.
May anyone help me on this issue. I have debugged the code as well, while debugging, the code is getting executed but the result is not taking any effect on the screen. I can see the cursor blinking on that field as well. Thanks in advance. Following is my Code :

```
namespace PX.Objects.IN
{
    public class INTransferEntry_Extension : PXGraphExtension<INTransferEntry>
    {
        #region Event Handlers
        
        protected void INRegister_RowSelected(PXCache cache, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e)
        {           
            if (e.Row == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            bool shouldDisable = ((INRegister)e.Row).Hold == false && ((INRegister)e.Row).Released == true;
            if (shouldDisable)
            {
                PXUIFieldAttribute.SetEnabled<INRegisterExt.usrExpReturnDate>(cache, e.Row, true);
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }
}

DAC FIELD

namespace PX.Objects.IN
{
  public class INRegisterExt : PXCacheExtension<PX.Objects.IN.INRegister>
  {
    #region UsrExpReturnDate
    [PXDBDate]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName="Expected Return Date")]

    public virtual DateTime? UsrExpReturnDate { get; set; }
    public abstract class usrExpReturnDate : PX.Data.BQL.BqlDateTime.Field<usrExpReturnDate> { }
    #endregion
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The document is in released status. There are mechanisms to prevent field editing when a document is in a closed state. It is not recommended to enable fields in this situation.

To enable the fields you need to revert the mechanism blocking editing. It is often the `AllowUpdate` property of the data  view that is used to do so but it can also be automation steps or the workflow system.

When re-enabling AllowUpdate, you need to disable and re-enable the fields:

```
Base.transfer.AllowUpdate = true;
PXUIFieldAttribute.SetEnabled(sender, e.Row, false);
PXUIFieldAttribute.SetEnabled<INRegisterExt.usrExpReturnDate>(cache, e.Row, true);
```

Comment: Hi Hugues, thanks again, its working fine now. But i am confused with certain things, the same code which i have provided allows me to enable or disable UDF in the AR301000 screen why not in this IN304000 screen ? why i need to set AllowUpdate property of the dataview to true for IN30400 screen..May you please suggest someting on this topic. Thanks

Comment: It's because the graph of IN304000 screen sets AllowUpdate=false when the document is in released status to prevent field value modification. When all fields are disabled, it's usually done with AllowUpdate or Automation Steps/Workflow system. You need to revert that to allow editing again but note that it is not recommended. When documents are closed they shouldn't be editable.

Comment: Thanks for your exposure comment Hugues. Appreciate it. Now its clear to me. :)